# Is there built-in heapify class/method in java?

Tags: java

Someone told me there is built-in heapify class/method in java. But I can not find it.
Now, I want to use it in my project. So is there someone who knows that?

Comment: Did you try the person that told you about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `heapify` method is implemented in `java.util.PriorityQueue`:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java

Line 673.

It is used to create a heap from a collection.

Comment: thanks, I just know priority queue is implemented with heap.